# Gii With Yiibooster and YiiBoilerplate

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I am new to Yii framework, infact new to php. I have downloaded YiiBoilerplate (clevertech-YiiBoilerplate-abe2511)and followed the instructions mentioned on http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/374/yiiboilerplate-setup-a-professional-project-structure-in-seconds/ page.

I want to access Gii but I am not sure how do I do that ? I am trying to use

`[http://localhost:8080/pm1/backend/www/index.php?r=gii]` url but it gets to the default backend page and not to the gii page.

Without YiiBoilerplate I was able to access Gii using [http://localhost:8080/pm1/index?r=gii]

Please let me know how do I access Gii when using YiiBoilerplate or point to tutorial if any configuration is required.

Comment: it wont work - how,what?

Comment: @bool.dev I have updated question. it gets to the default backend page and not to the gii page, I guess its not understanding r=gii

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default YiiBoilerplate has gii disabled, so you'll have to enable it. If you check the *backend/www/index.php* file you'll see the line:

```
$config=require('backend/config/main.php');
```

which tells us the exact config file that is being loaded: *backend/config/main.php*.
Within *backend/config/main.php* enable the gii module by uncommenting the following lines:

```
'modules' => array(
    'gii' => array(
        'class' => 'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password' => 'clevertech',
        'generatorPaths' => array(
            'bootstrap.gii'
        )
    )
),
```

Now you can access gii by following the url: `http://localhost:8080/pm1/backend/www/index.php/gii/default/login`.

A few pointers:

- by default `urlFormat` is `path` that's why even after enabling gii `index.php?r=gii` will not work
- also they have set `showScriptName` to false, which means the `index.php` will not be shown, to work without `index.php` you'll have to do some web-server redirects, read [the guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#hiding-x-23x) on tips for that.
- incase you don't want to hide index.php just comment this line in *backend/config/main-local.php*:

  ```
  'showScriptName' => $params['url.showScriptName'],
  ```
- also read the [gii part of the guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii).

Comment: my advice for now would be to stick with a commented showScriptName, to avoid unnecessary complications before you get started. you can always uncomment it later, and have clean urls, of course with the necessary web-server redirect

Comment: if you are having trouble, you can always comment, and ask for clarifications. i just made an edit to the url that will lead you to the gii login screen directly

Comment: I had enabled gii enabled but I was not sure about the url. Now using the url you mentioned I was able to go to gii login page but when I click login it takes me to this url http://localhost:8080/pm1/backend/www/gii/default/index/ which is Not Found. Not sure what else is missing.

Comment: yes, that is bound to happen, just comment that line in _backend/config/main-local.php_ : `// 'showScriptName' => $params['url.showScriptName']`, that will redirect you to `http://localhost:8080/pm1/backend/www/index.php/gii/default/index/` , and you won't get Not Found. see the middle 2 points in the answer.

Comment: Maybe it was cache, I had already tried commenting showScriptName, cleared cache and now its working :) thanks